# Get Normal JFrame Bounds while Maximized

Tags: java, swing, window, persistence, jframe

I am attempting to create a JFrame that remembers its window position, size and whether it was maximized or not. It should be simple enough to use a WindowListener for the windowClosing event and save it's bounds to Preferences.

In order for this to work (as set up below), I would need to extract the JFrame's normal (NORMAL ExtendedState) bounds while it is maximized (MAXIMIZED_BOTH ExtendedState). Is this at all possible? Considering that the normal bounds are stored somewhere in order for it to revert back.

```
//...
addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {
    ///...
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        prefs.putBoolean("win_max",win_max);
        if(winmax)
        {
            //win_x=?
            //win_y=?
            //win_w=?
            //win_h=?
        }
        else
        {
            win_x=getX();
            win_y=getY();
            win_w=getWidth();
            win_h=getHeight();
        }
        prefs.putInt("win_x",win_x);
        prefs.putInt("win_y",win_y);
        prefs.putInt("win_w",win_w);
        prefs.putInt("win_h",win_h);
    }
});
//...
```

I apologise if this is a really simple question. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Simply save and restore `extendedState` and `bounds` properties (using their respective getter/setter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I did.  The model instance saved the frame origin, frame bounds, and frame state.

```
protected int           state;

protected Point         frameOrigin;

protected Rectangle     frameBounds;
```

This is a component listener that I created to capture frame data changes.

```
    frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent event) {
            if (isMaximized()) {
                model.setFrameOrigin(frame.getLocation());
            } else {
                model.setFrameBounds(frame.getBounds());
            }
            model.setFrameState(frame.getExtendedState());
        }
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent event) {
            model.setFrameState(frame.getExtendedState());
        }
    });
```

This is the code that I had to perform after packing the frame to set the frame to the last used state.

```
    frame.pack();
    if (options.getFrameBounds().getWidth() > 0) {
        frame.setExtendedState(options.getState());
        if (isMaximized()) {
            frame.setLocation(options.getFrameOrigin());
        } else {
            frame.setBounds(options.getFrameBounds());
        }
    }
    model.setFrameState(frame.getExtendedState());
    model.setFrameBounds(frame.getBounds());
    model.setFrameOrigin(frame.getLocation());
```

And here's the `isMaximized` method.

```
public boolean isMaximized() {
    return (frame.getExtendedState() & JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) 
            == JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH;
}
```

I saved the frame data in a properties file, but you can save and restore the frame data how you want.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your class which derives from `JFrame`, add the following code...

```
private Rectangle m_normalBounds;

@Override
public void setExtendedState(int state)
{
   if (getExtendedState() == 0)
      m_bounds = getBounds();        // Capture the normal bounds since the state is changing

   super.setExtendedState(state);
}

private Rectangle getNormalBounds()  // Always returns the normal bounds
{
   Rectangle bounds;

   if (getExtendedState() == 0)
      return(getBounds());

   return(m_normalBounds);
}
```